# My geosearch is not working with leaflet onClick

Tags: react-leaflet

I am trying to have search control and onClick event handler to add Marker on my leaflet map. But search control is not working with onClick, but working fine when I don't have any onClick handlers.

```
class GeoSearch extends MapControl {

    createLeafletElement(opts) {
        const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider()
        const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
            provider: provider,
            position: 'bottomleft',
            style: 'button',
        })
        return searchControl
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {map} = this.props.leaflet
        map.addControl(this.leafletElement)
    }

}

export default withLeaflet(GeoSearch)
```

---

```
<Map
  ...

  onClick={this.addMarker}
>
<Search />
</Map>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `addMarker` event is also triggered once control is clicked, right? If so, this is the expected behavior since  control elements emit events that are propagated to map. To suppress control events from propagation [`L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#domevent-disableclickpropagation) could be utilized, here is a *modified* version of `GeoSearch` component:

```
class GeoSearch extends MapControl {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
  }

  createLeafletElement(opts) {
    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
    const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
      provider: provider,
      position: "topleft"
    });
    return searchControl;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet;
    map.addControl(this.leafletElement);
    //To suppress control events from propagation
    const containerDiv = this.leafletElement.getContainer();
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(containerDiv);
  }
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chbm8o)